# Applying filter on parent if it has been applied on children AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a list with items and have applied filter on those items by value from text box. I want to get new filtered list with parent and its children if parent has at least one filtered item.If doesn't, that parent should not be displayed.

For an example: If I enter "3D" in the text box I don't want to get "Day parts" and "Week parts" listed below as they don't have children anymore after filtering.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <input type="text" data-ng-model="inputValue.name"/>
<ul data-ng-repeat="condition in conditions">

        <div data-ng-click="setHeadingStatus(condition)">
            <div>
                {{condition.name}}
            </div>
        <li ng-repeat="item in condition.items | filter:inputValue">

                    <div class="custom-typeahead-list-title">{{item.name}}</div>
                    <div class="custom-typeahead-list-desc">{{item.description}}</div>

        </li>
            </div>
</ul>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope , $filter){

$scope.countryCode = 1;

$scope.conditions = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Experiences",
    "expanded": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "3D"

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Imax"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "D-Box"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "THX"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Day parts",
    "expanded": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Early Bird"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Matinee"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Last Night"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Week parts",
    "expanded": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Wednesday"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Weekend"
        }
    ]
} 
  ]

}
```

Here is the example of it
  http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3Nx/48/

Answer (score 1):

You can put an `ng-show` on the div that displays each block, and set the expression to the filtered length;

```
<div data-ng-show="(condition.items | filter:inputValue).length > 0" data-ng-click="setHeadingStatus(condition)">
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/top5rj6q/1/)

Comment: Your solution has fixed visually the issue, but introduced another one. It would be great to create custom filter which will return new filtered list.